# Service that provides a Json AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Hi i have a problem whith this service

```
app.service('myStorage',function($http, $localStorage){
this.getFilms = function(){
    /* Carga la lista de peliculas de localStorage si existe*/
    if ($localStorage.films && $localStorage.films.length!=0) {
        return $localStorage.films;
        console.log($localStorage.films);
    }else{
        $http.get("json/films.json")
       .then(function(res){
        console.log(res.data);
          return res.data;
        });
    }
}
```

});

This console.log works fine and give me an array of objects, but in the controller:

```
function($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $localStorage, myStorage) {
    $scope.films=myStorage.getFilms();
    console.log($scope.films);
```

the console says undefined, any help?

Comment: Most probably you are not injecting dependencies properly. Could you please post the entire controller's code?

Comment: Which console.log are you referring, the one in the if or the else ? If what is being printed in the console ?

Comment: it's probably because `$scope.films` is assigned before promise is resolved, resulting in an unassigned result value.

Comment: Your service is async

Comment: @VadimLanda that's doubtful because he would get a reference error

Comment: the dependencies seems work fine, and the log is the else one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be returning a promise instead. Like this:

```
app.service('myStorage',function($http, $localStorage, $q){
  this.getFilms = function(){
    if ($localStorage.films && $localStorage.films.length!=0) {
      return $q.when($localStorage.films);
    } else {
      return $http.get("json/films.json").then(function(res){
        console.log(res.data);
        return res.data;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And, now in controller,

```
function($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $localStorage, myStorage) {
  myStorage.getFilms().then(function(res) {
    $scope.films = res;
    console.log($scope.films);        
  })
  ...
})
```

Comment: This is correct but consider using  $q.when and then the first branch is only one line of code

Comment: @AluanHaddad sure. good point, too habituated with this one. :( will update it. thanks!

Comment: most excellent! If I could up vote twice ...

Comment: As for being habituated, at least you broke that cycle for $http no need for Q there and you don't use it, and that's a good thing

Comment: I had tried something similar before but the console tells me "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" :(

Comment: Because you forgot to return the promise

Comment: Thanks in the end it works, I appreciate your help¡

Comment: @David_ult glad that helped a little :)